# Python Program to Implement Bucket Sort: Is there a better way to create a bucket?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, bucket

I have initialized the bucket with np.empty and after with np.nan. Is it the better way? I did not know how to create a truly empty array!  I need an EMPTY array with 10 rows and len(array) columns

The code below is the first part of the algorithm. The code is working!

Another question: I used "for" to iterate through the bucket, which is a numpy array.Is it correct?

```
import numpy as np

class BucketSort():
    def __init__(self,array):
        self.array = array
    def distribution_pass(self):
        bucket = np.empty((10,len(self.array)),dtype=int)
        bucket[:] = np.nan
        #rows =[]
       # cols = []
        for num in array:
            for j in range(bucket.shape[1]):
                bucket[num % 10, j] = num
                #rows.append(num%10)
                #cols.append(j)
                break
                print()

        return bucket
    def gathering_pass(self):
        array = []
        self.bucket = BucketSort.distribution_pass(self)
        for i in range(self.bucket.shape[0]):
            for j in range(self.bucket.shape[1]):
              if not np.isnan(self.bucket[i,j]):
                  #print(self.bucket[i,j])
                  array.append(self.bucket[i, j])

        return array


def main(array):
    bucket = BucketSort(array)
    BucketSort.distribution_pass(bucket)
    array = BucketSort.gathering_pass(bucket)
    return array


array = [97,3,100]
print(main(array))
#bucket = BucketSort(array)
#print(bucket.distribution_pass())
#print(bucket.gathering_pass())
```

Input: `[97,3,100]`

Output: `[100,3,97]`

Comment: Re: is this correct – did you test it?

Comment: clearly describe your problem

Comment: Why are you using `numpy` here??? As an aside, `BucketSort.distribution_pass(self)` should be `self.distribution_pass()`

Comment: Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  You seem to be asking for a code review and algorithmic help.  Stack Overflow is generally to fix specific problems with almost-working code.  Also see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you have a specific problem.

Comment: @mkrieger1 The code is working but It is not finished yet!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I need a EMPTY array with 10 rows and len(array) columns!

Comment: @Prune The code is working! It needs just little adjustments!

Comment: but why **numpy**??

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I used numpy because I dont know how to do it with python lists... Could you suggest anything better? I am noob!

Comment: Please review the intro tour.  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) would also help.  You dropped 35 lines of code on us with a too-broad request for improvement.  Now, as others ask questions about what you need, you identify several different issues.  The SO standard is one, clear question per posting.  This is why my closure vote still stands: you're asking for individual inspection and tutorial support, which is not within the SO charter.

Comment: @Prune I disagree: I asked two specifics questions about the code!

Comment: Which is one too many.

Comment: @mkrieger1 The code is correct but I did not finished the sorting yet...